# How to detect onfocus and blur event of ion-searchbar in ionic2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, dom-events

I'm now using ionic2 to build an app. I want to detect when the searchbar input get focus and when it blur so that I can hide or show some components according to the current status. (For example, show some suggestions when the user clicks this searchbar.)

This is my code:

```
<ion-searchbar #searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchInput"></ion-searchbar>
```

However, I found that this component seems don't have these two events.I have tried to add an event listener like this, but it didn't work:

```
<ion-searchbar #searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchInput" (focus)="searchBarOnFocus()"></ion-searchbar>
```

So can I implement this feature in some other ways?

Thanks in advance!

---

There are two documents for ion-searchbar:
[component document](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#searchbar) &
[api document](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To catch focus / blur events on searchbar you should use (ionFocus) and (ionBlur) instead of Angular's (focus) and (blur). Works like a charm for me!

```
<ion-searchbar #searchbar placeholder="Type an address" showCancelButton
               (ionBlur)="checkBlur()"
               (ionFocus)="checkFocus()"></ion-searchbar>
```